# Obtain the column of a matrix that is composed by tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I'm a bit confuse how to reach tuples index and group them in a single tuple. My function receives a 3x3 matrix, my `tab`, and an integer that corresponds to the matrix column index.

Comment: Really beginner level question, sorry but SO is not here to solve homework problem, please show us your approach of solving this particular problem.

Comment: I wonder if the part about raising a `ValueError` exception is a fundamental part of your requirements… if I try the accepted answer with `n=4`, as in your specification, then I receive a different error message `"IndexError: tuple index out of range"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what blocks you, it is the same as indexing into a list of lists:

```
def obtain_column(tab, c):
    return tuple(row[c] for row in tab)
    # take element at position c in each row, and make a tuple


tab = ((1,-1,0),
       (1,0,-1),
       (1,-1,0))

print(obtain_column(tab, 0))
print(obtain_column(tab, 1))
print(obtain_column(tab, 2))
```

#### output of the columns:

```
(1, 1, 1)
(-1, 0, -1)
(0, -1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time! It help me a lot! Actually, an easy way to do it. Doing the same for the lines of the matrix.

Comment: Cool, you are very welcome. For the rows, you can directly get the entire row with `tab[r]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ret = ()

for row in tab:
    ret += (row[c],)  # the , is for adding the integer as a tuple element.

return ret
```

Note that the code above assumes each tuple has an element in index c. You might need to add something to check that, depending on your full program.

Comment: Refer to Reblochon Masque's answer, it is more "python-y". This is a demonstration of the process of creating the new tuple, instead of using a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done

1. transposing the *tuple of tuples* using the well known idiom `zip(*iterable)` to obtain the columns of `tab` as the elements of the `zip` object,
2. then in a *list comprehension* we count the column objects starting from 1 and we discard all the columns whose count doesn't match `n`
3. if a column count matched, the only element of the list `col` is the tuple, generated by `zip(*tab)` corresponding to the requested column
4. if `col` is not the empty list we can return its unique element — the requested column as a tuple
5. otherwise no column count matched `n`, `col` is the null list, we don't `return` and so we have to raise a `ValueError`, according to your specification

so

```
In [35]: def obtain_column(t, n):
    ...:     col = [c for i, c in enumerate(zip(*tab), 1) if i==n]
    ...:     if col : return col[0]
    ...:     raise ValueError('obtain_column: invalid argument %d.'%n)
    ...: for i in (1,2,4): print(obtain_column(tab, i))
(1, 1, 1)
(-1, 0, -1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-1c03f33aa1cf> in <module>
      3     if col : return col[0]
      4     raise ValueError('obtain_column: invalid argument %d.'%n)
----> 5 for i in (1,2,4): print(obtain_column(tab, i))

<ipython-input-35-1c03f33aa1cf> in obtain_column(t, n)
      2     col = [c for i, c in enumerate(zip(*tab), 1) if i==n]
      3     if col : return col[0]
----> 4     raise ValueError('obtain_column: invalid argument %d.'%n)
      5 for i in (1,2,4): print(obtain_column(tab, i))

ValueError: obtain_column: invalid argument 4.

In [36]:
```